# linux c program is there another way to read logs than reading files in /var/log?

Tags: c, linux, logging, linux-kernel

Hello dear community of stackoverflow,

at the moment im programming a tool in c that monitors the linux log files which can be found in /var/log, the c program reads the logs directly from the log files
but reading the log files from an c program is is not very good because the user can manipulate log files or the logs got saved in different file e.g. instead it got saved in syslog it got saved in syslog.1.

Because of this disadvantages i want to ask if there is any alternative in linux instead of reading the files?
Maybe it is possible with an kernel module that catches these logs?

Thank you for any answer!

Comment: No. Btw, for monitoring on linux, use `inotify`.

Comment: Note: syslog works over a network(UDP, IIRC) It is possible to ship the log messages to a remote machine, and store them there (as well) And, you can even set up your own receiver for the messages.

Comment: I guess you're asking for an API that abstracts read access to log files.  There is none.  To read logs you must open the file -- wherever it is, which is not necessarily on the system(s) that generates the log messages.

Comment: @wildplasser Thank you very much for your answer! Do you know how i can accomplish this, or do you have any source where i can read more about how i can do this in c?

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3164 1) syslogd has a config file . 2) setting up an UDP-receiver is relatively easy.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate is to use either `/proc/kmsg` or `/dev/kmsg`. User cannot modify these sources of logs. Format will be a bit different but you can change your program to adapt it.